# Upgrading old .net 2 solution - error loading assembly

Tags: .net

I have a 10 year old .NET site, that i now am making some tweaks to.

To make my tweaks work, i had to upgrade the site to .NET 4. That works.
One of the add-ons, is coming from an external assembly, that i know works.

My problem is, that i am getting an error `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

The site is not in a VS solution - i am working from a plain text edition at the moment.

What can i do to fix the issue?

Comment: It is rather strange a case, as `System.Web.Helpers` is something for .NET Framework 4.x, which won't match your description of `.NET 3.5`. Please post more details like how you hit this error, and what are exactly the things deployed. Otherwise, nobody can guess what's up.

Comment: @LexLi sorry. Typo - i meant .NET 4. I updated my question

Comment: Then have you checked NuGet? https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft-web-helpers/

Comment: @LexLi But the site is not in a VS solution - so i should create one, or?

Comment: Definitely create a VS solution if you're working in a .NET project.

Comment: @LexLi created a empty solution and added the files. Added the Nuget package from above, but the same error still persists? :-/

Comment: Is that an old web site project? It is time to switch to web application project. I don't know how to make NuGet work for web sites.